# django rest framework request vs self.request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

in djnago rest framework what is difference between self.request and request in
why we cant always use request and exactly in what situations we need to use self.request or request

```
class MyView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = self.request.data
        login(request, user)
```

i try to print them and both of them return same thing

```
<rest_framework.request.Request: POST '/url/sub_url'>
```

so why we user like

```
data = self.request.data
login(request, user)
```

Answer (score 6):

the `request` argument is passed to the `post` method. like any normal function that you can define and use its arguments.

But since `post` is a method it takes `self` argument. you can access the class methods and attributes including `request`.

And they're the same.

When `request` is passed to your function just use `request` but if not and you need request use `self.request`.

Comment: so when i post something i can access it by post and what you saying is i can access data with request.data and in this situation i dont need self.request.post ?

Comment: no you already have `request` argument in your function. you can do it like this `data = request.data`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using function based views, you wont be able to use self.request. Here as you are using class based views, you can access it both ways.